# Does Activity that bind to a Service will keep run in background?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding, foreground-service

I have an Activity that receives locations in location listener. 
This Activity, is starting a Service by startService() and then, bind to this service with bindService() in order to share data with the service.

The bind and the unbind is done in response to button click inside onClick. 
something like:

```
onClick(){
  if(!bind){
         startService(serviceIntent)
         bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
         bind=true;
}else{
      unbindService(mConnection);
      stopService(serviceIntent);
      bind=false;
    }
}
```

now my question is, at some point my Activity goes to the background like when pressing the Home button, and the service keeps running and the bind is still intact!

So will this bind will help to keep the Activity running in the background?

The service, is a foregroundService with associated notification, when the user push on the notification it will open the background Activity.

Answer (score 0):

No, the activity can be destroyed on any time while on background depends on your current memory status in the system (if your app priority is not high enough in the system while android needs to free memory it will probably be destoryed). the service would keep running of course, and remain that way if it was set as STICKY + notification which you wrote you set. but no guaranree that the activity would stay alive in any point while in background.